# Dynamically select or make new database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an invoicing application which expects users to select the financial year at the beginning of session.

Which means when they select a particular year, a new table (or whole new database) is created for that year if it doesn't already exist otherwise it selects existing table accordingly.

I tried using 'Session' but in dbcontext class it somehow wouldn't work.

Please suggest the correct and efficient way to accomplish this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating databases on the fly is in just about every commercial application a bad idea. Even splitting databases is suspect over domains unless you have good reason to do so. Databases are more than capable of querying by year, or customer or anything else. i would consider all the options that keep a well formalized and single database over anything else first

Comment: Thanks, I understand but what would other options be like?

Answer (score 0):

as i know there is a CreateModel or CreateDatabase if not exists option is available in EF

```
public class SchoolDBContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext(): base("SchoolDBConnectionString") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchoolDBContext>());

        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new SchoolDBInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

also here is the link
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have used this already but the thing is the table names have to be as per user's input. Can't get to make that happen. Eg. If user chooses the year 2017-18 the code should look something like:     public DbSet<Student> Students201718 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards201718 { get; set; } Thanks.